# Check textfile for arguments Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two Python scripts: 
Script 1: Checks elements on a webpage and writes them to a file.
Script 2: Reads from this file and uses the contents as argument for an if statement. 
 This is the part that I'm unsure about.

The text file has at least 500 items all on new lines, and I want to check if these items are still there when I revisit the site.

```
    def read_input_file(self):
    inFile = open("page_items.txt","r")
    if inFile == current_content:
        do.stuff
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the first script to scrape the site again and save it in a set. Then use .issubset to check if everything in 'inFile' is contained within the current_site?

```
current_site = set(scraped_items)
if set(inFile).issubset(current_site):
     do.stuff
```

Comment: I never heard of "sets" before, but it sounds like it's exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: They are the python representation of the mathematical concept, you might consider reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics) to get a better idea of what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the sets where not really what I was looking for after all. Mainly because the scraped contents needed to survive a reboot. So the text file was the only option I could think of.

I did find a solution however, instead of scraping the current_site and matching that with the the infile I now start with the infile and search for that line on the current_site, using Selenium.

Here is what I came up with, it's not very clean but maybe it's useful to somebody from the future

```
import linecache            

for i in range(0, 200):
        scraped_content = linecache.getline('scraped.txt', count)
        scraped_content = str(scraped_content).rstrip()
        search_path = "//*[contains(text(),'",scraped_content,"')]"
        joined_string = "".join(str(x) for x in search_path)

        scroll_down = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        scroll_down.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        scroll_to_element = None
        while not scroll_to_element:
            try:
                scroll_to_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(joined_string)
                time.sleep(1)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print "Searching for Content:", scraped_content
                break

        if scroll_to_element != None:
            try:
                print scraped_content,"Found!"
```